# Is it better to age a wine in bottles rather than bulk aging?

Tags: bottling, wine

My partner and I are brewing a 6-gallon wine batch, and we disagree over when to bottle it.
It's been in the carboy for approximately 8 months, and I've read here and on other sites that bulk aging should be kept to a minimum of 1 year. Is this true? Would the result be better to bottle now or in several months?

Answer (score 3):

Bulk aging has one advantage over bottle aging, it ages much faster.  Once in the bottle, wine will still age, but less.

Also, if you add Potasium Metabisulfate right before you bottle it will stop the yeast. A big way fermented beverages age(not distilled) is from the yeast still living.  This will lessen the aging process.

**Overall:** Do what tastes the best.  Take a sample.  If it tastes good, then bottle it.  If it doesn't, age it a little longer in the carboy.  I've heard of some people aging their wine for only 4 weeks before drinking it.  It really depends on the type of wine and what you want.

Answered by: The Gastrograph team